# Javascript window.open() doesn't download file

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, window.open

In Chrome window.open() downloads the ICS file, but in MS Edge, it's trying to open the file in a different tab. How do I ensure Edge downloads the file in the same way Chrome does.

Code:

```
var icsMSG = ""; // Here goes the calendar details
window.open("data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Edge Legacy? Edge Legacy only support [`msSaveBlob` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh772331(v=vs.85)) to download files. You can update your Edge to the latest Edge Chromium to make `window.open()` download or use `msSaveBlob` in Edge Legacy.

If you still want to use Edge Legacy, you can refer to the following code to use `msSaveBlob` to download:

```
    var icsMSG = ""; // Here goes the calendar details
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) { // For IE & Edge Legacy
        var blob = new Blob([icsMSG], { type: 'text/calendar;charset=utf-8\'' })
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'download.ics')
    }
    else {
        window.open("data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG));
    }
```